# Constructor in class cannot be applied to given types error when calling methods

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, compiler-errors

Im trying to write a program using inheritance, that will print the most cost effective broadband/telephone package based on the users usage. (so the basic idea is that the user enters the amount of minutes and MB of broadband required and the program prints the closest match in terms of usage.)
 I keep getting the errors "Constructors  Account in class Account cannot be applied to given types" whenever I try to call methods from other classes
the Error in the picture below

Error message in terminal

[image]

User Class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class UserAccount {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        BronzeAccount newBronzeAccount;
        SilverAccount newSilverAccount;
        GoldAccount newGoldAccount;
        double dayPhone;
        double evePhone;
        double extBroadband;
```

Calling methods in user class:

```
newBronzeAccount = new BronzeAccount(dayPhone, evePhone, extBroadband);
newSilverAccount = new SilverAccount(dayPhone, evePhone, extBroadband);
newGoldAccount = new GoldAccount(dayPhone, evePhone, extBroadband);


System.out.println("Account Summary for Bronze Account");
newBronzeAccount.printPackageBronze();

System.out.println("Account Summary for Silver Account");
newSilverAccount.printPackageSilver();

System.out.println("Account Summary for Gold Account");
newGoldAccount.printPackageGold();
```

Constructors from sub classes:

```
public BronzeAccount(double newdayPhone, double newevePhone,
    doublenewextBroadband,double newtotCost){

public SilverAccount(double newdayPhone, double newevePhone,
    double newextBroadband, double newtotCost, String newextras){
 super(newdayPhone, newevePhone, newextBroadband, newtotCost);

 public GoldAccount(double newdayPhone, double  newevePhone, 
     double newextBroadband, double newtotCost, String newextras, 
     String newdmusic){
     super(newdayPhone, newevePhone, newextBroadband, newtotCost, newextras);
```

I've tried changing the variables to those that are declared in the sub-classes which seems to make more sense as thats what the error message seems to require but neither way seems to work.

Comment: You're not passing `newtotCost` as a parameter which is required by your constructors for the `BronzeAccount`, and for the rest of the classes you're not passing the amount of parameters again that the rest of the constructors in the subclasses require.

Comment: your subclass requires 4 arguments but you are passing arguments which are not matching the four.

Comment: Just an FYI, in situations like these it's better to read compiler error messages because they make complete sense before posting questions. [Read about constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) too.

Answer (score 0):

```
new SilverAccount(dayPhone, evePhone, extBroadband);
```

This means that the constructor accepts 3 arguments. but in `SilverAccount` class you've written the signature as below

```
public SilverAccount(double newdayPhone, double newevePhone,
double newextBroadband, double newtotCost, String newextras)
```

And, Similar mistakes with other classes also.